# display two table data at a time in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to to display two tables information at a time.

```
List<int> order_track = db.Order_Trackings.Where(e => e.UID == id).Select(q => q.ID).ToList();
            if (order_track == null)
            {
                var rate = db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate).Take(5);
            }
          List<int> fidList = db.OrderFoods.Where(q => order_track.Contains(q.OID)).Select(q => q.FID).ToList();
            var qs = (from x in fidList
                      group x by x into g
                      let count = g.Count()
                      orderby count descending
                      select new { KEY = g.Key });

            if (order_track.Count == 2)
            {
                var one = qs;
                List<int> idList = new List<int>();
                foreach (var val in one)
                {
                    idList.Add(val.KEY);
                }
                var food = db.Foods.Where(q => idList.Contains(q.ID));

                var rate = db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate).FirstorDefault();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rate);
```

I want to do something like this I hope you will understand what i am trying to achieve Thanks in advance.

```
var food = db.Foods.Where(q => idList.Contains(q.ID)&&db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate).FirstorDefault());
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, rate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine the two results into one variable, then the easiest way to do so is by creating an [anonymous object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), like this:

```
var result = new
{
    food = db.Foods.Where(q => idList.Contains(q.ID)),
    rate = db.Ratings.OrderByDescending(e => e.Rate).FirstorDefault()
};
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
```

You could also create a `class` with two `properties` and then create an instance of that class, but if this is the only place where you would use that class then I wouldn't bother doing that.

Comment: it is returning with food and rate headings but i dont want like that i want normal list

Comment: how to use result.distinct here ?

Comment: Do you want e.g. the Rating for each Food? Please make that clear, and in that case also: how are the two related, e.g. does `Food` have a `RatingID`?